# Are there variants (described below) of $3n + 1$ conjecture where the answer is known?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations

The $3n + 1$ conjecture states that if you take any natural number $n_j$, and if it is even then set $n_{j+1} = n_j/2$, otherwise set $n_{j+1} = 3n_j + 1$, then no matter what natural number $n_0$ you start with, eventually you will reach $n_j = 1$ for some $j$. It is still an open problem and believed to be very hard.

Has anybody studied this problem with different and/or more primes than just $3$ and $2$? For example, let's say that if a number $n$ is divisible by 3 then we divide by 3, and if it's divisible by 2 then we divide by 2, otherwise we form the number $7n + 1$. Are there any variants like this where the answer is known whether you will always reach $1$ no matter what natural number you start with?

Comment: (aka Collatz Conjecture)

Comment: There is the $0n+1$ conjecture.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, many variants are known.  If you're making up such a variant, it's not hard to construct one where you get a nontrivial cycle.  On the other hand, [the general problem is undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Undecidable_Generalizations).

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of Conway's undecidability result, which establishes we can't hope to solve these problems in general, at least, not with any universal proof mechanism that settles all cases simultaneously. There is one small difference, though, I am allowing more than one number to divide by. In any event, it would be interesting to know "how far" we've been able to settle the question, i.e. the most general classes of parameters where the answer is known. Maybe Lagarias has a treatment of that?